# ActionController::RoutingError for font in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am getting the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/fonts/material-icons/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.ttf")
```

Here is my css.scss that calls the file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Design Iconic Font';
  src: font-url('/assets/fonts/material-icons/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.eot?v=1.0.1');
  src: font-url('/assets/fonts/material-icons/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.eot?#iefix&v=1.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'), font-url('/assets/fonts/material-icons/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.woff?v=1.0.1') format('woff'), font-url('/assets/fonts/material-icons/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.ttf?v=1.0.1') format('truetype'), font-url('/assets/fonts/material-icons/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.svg?v=1.0.1#Material-Design-Iconic-Font') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I know the file is there.  I am getting the same error for all of the other files as well.  I am using Rails 4.1

Answer (score 2):

Changing it to this fixed it:

```
font-url('material-icons/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.eot?v=1.0.1');
```

Answer (score 0):

If this helps you, I developed a gem to add Google Material Icons to your Rails project.

https://rubygems.org/gems/material_icons/

This gem add an updated version of Material Icons and new version provide with a simple helper to build icons in your views.